# API in nodeJS which serves a video from buffer, which is hosted on iis, working in localhost but not through domain name

Tags: node.js, iis, video-streaming

- My nodejs backend server is running in iis
- All APIs working through hosted api endpoint and localhost both

I want to stream video through my nodeJs Server

- I wrote an API which returns readable stream of video, from input path
- Tried to stream video directly through fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)
  Which is working fine. From localhost as well domain name endpoint
- Tried to stream through Readble.from(buffer) working fine through localhost in prod server where my app is hosted

Problem is when i try to get video through domain endpoint for same Readable.from(buffer) it loads small video window no video is playing

and in network section only one video response is there with 300 bytes of size

Comment: Do you get any error messages when no video is playing? You can check if there is relevant content in the console.

Comment: How did you hook Node.js on IIS? IISNode or HttpPlatformHandler?

Comment: @samwu in console network section i am getting video response with 300 byets

Comment: @LexLi I have written rule with server url, and server variables inside rule

Comment: Is there any relevant error message? You can also check the Event Viewer.